# Publishing commands to device in IBM IoT using MQTT in Java

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

I am currently trying to publish a command to a specific topic in the IBM IoT Foundation MQTT Broker using a Java web application. My application is already able to listen to device events and act on them, however publishing commands to the device is a problem. I know for sure that my device is listening to the proper topic for commands, so what could be the problem? More specifically, here is the command I call to publish to the topic (from my Java app):

```
publish("iot-2/cmd/" + MQTTUtil.getDefaultCmdId() + "/fmt/json", rawJSONCommand, false, 0); 
System.out.println("Finished sending command!");
```

Where the "publish" method is defined as follows:

```
public void publish(String topic, String message, boolean retained, int qos) { // check if client is connected
if (isMqttConnected()) 
{
// create a new MqttMessage from the message string 
MqttMessage mqttMsg = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes()); 
// set retained flag 
mqttMsg.setRetained(retained); 
// set quality of service 
mqttMsg.setQos(qos);
try { 
System.out.println("About to send!"); 
client.publish(topic, mqttMsg); 
System.out.println("Finished sending!"); } 
catch (MqttPersistenceException e)
{ e.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (MqttException e)
{ e.printStackTrace(); } }
else {
System.out.println("Connection lost!"); connectionLost(null); 
} }
```

All that happens is that I enter the method, I get "About to send!" printed on my console as the code specifies, and then the actual 'client.publish(topic, mqttMsg)' call blocks my program indefinitely.. Eventually, after blocking for a while, I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState checkForActivity SEVERE: a:2uwqwc:<MY_APP_NAME>: Timed out as no write activity, keepAlive=60,000 lastOutboundActivity=1,452,646,209,624 lastInboundActivity=1,452,646,149,303 time=1,452,646,329,628 lastPing=0
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are publishing from an application, are you specifying the device type and device id?

```
myAppClient.publishCommand(deviceType, deviceId, "stop", data);
```

Refer to section in documentation about publishing commands to connected devices. 
https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/java/java_cli_app.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I changed the code to also use the device type and id:

`publish("iot-2/type/" + MQTTUtil.getDefaultDeviceType()
    + "/id/" + deviceMAC + "/cmd/" + MQTTUtil.getDefaultCmdId()
    + "/fmt/json", rawJSONCommand, false, 0);
`
However, I am not using the ApplicationClient class but rather the MqttClient class as seen here:
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.html

Could this be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I think the problem may be because you are trying to send message as "retained" and IoTF does not support MQTT Retained messages. Can you test with the retain flag off and see if it works then? Sorry I didn't notice that before.

Comment: Thanks for the update! In fact, I do always set the retained flag to false (its passed in as an input parameter thats always false if you look at the code above). It still doesn't work however frown emoticon Really not sure where I'm going wrong here, hope you'll have some idea about it!