# IoT Gateway and Cloud Server messaging

Tags: java, websocket, mqtt, iot

I’m implementing IoT Gateway (which is running in each premises) with my cloud server. The way I have designed is, IoT gateway establishes connection over web socket with cloud server to receive commands from mobile device. Mobile device connected over internet will pass commands to cloud server it in turns send commands to IoT gateway.  I want to receive all commands real time
What is best option to write command, IoT Gateway should listen for its data

- MQTT kind of message broker (It is suggested MQTT is good for Machine To Machine connection, but my use case is subscribe for a message and receive it)
- PUB/SUB mechanism (Kafka/Streaming)

It should be highly scalable and fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

There are projects on GitHub, which will serve as part of your needs. I can point you to [java sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-application-samples) which is for publishing commands to device(s). You can modify them according to your need.

Usually I use Kafka for collecting data from devices, then send them to some backend data processing. At backend Hadoop, Elastic search, Mongodb etc are kept. I use [NodeRed](https://flows.nodered.org) for visual flow editing. I guess you already have a plan for it.

You can look at similar topics discussed by particular vendor's service on StackOverflow for debugging/development like this one -- [Publishing commands to device in IBM IoT using MQTT in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843041/publishing-commands-to-device-in-ibm-iot-using-mqtt-in-java) .

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this type of service too in the last year and in my implementation I used MQTT ([emqtt](http://emqtt.io/) implementation of mqtt) because it is very good for Realtime services and it is fast enough to exchange command like turn the lamp on. In this project I used Kafka for collecting data from devices and send them to some data processing systems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using both MQTT and Kafka.
I use mqtt for device to device and device to data center messaging (with a partitioned  cluster of mosquitto brokers running in the DMZ for mqtt). Then on the backend I run a MQTT Kafka Source Connector which republishes all the mqtt traffic into Kafka topics (with the mqtt topic as the key) and into a bunch of Kafka Streams jobs for streaming analytics and some Kafka Sink Connectors to store the data long term in AWS S3 buckets or into various repositories for batch analytics or interactive queries (i.e. Mongodb, Hadoop, Elastic search, etc.)